# Homepage is not reachable in case of private pods?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods

While testing the syntax of podfile by using this commands.

```
$ pod --no-clean lib lint
```

It didn't passed the validation.
Gives the error like this-

```
-> sample-ios-pod (0.1.0)
- WARN  | The URL (https://github.com/MY_COMPANY_NAME/sample-ios-pod) is not reachable.

Pods project available at `/private/tmp/CocoaPods/Lint/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj` for inspection.
```

The above github url is one of my private repository.
Anybody know how to resolve that issue?

in-fact i went through http://guides.cocoapods.org/making/private-cocoapods.html
But didn't get anything :-(

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I know is to put a page there that is reachable (and don't gives an error code). We use private pages for our private pods that redirect to a login page when the user is not logged in and those work fine with `pod lib lint`.